# Relieving pain by massage

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

How come the pain in our body, primarily due to excessive physical exercises, vanishes after having a massage? What is the mechanism?

Comment: It probably increases the blood flow and so it is easier to clear out lactic acid, which can cause muscle pain.

Answer (score 3):

## Short Answer

What you're referring to is called ***Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness*** (DOMS).

We don't really know what causes DOMS, but it's most likely caused by a cascade effect started my muscle injury. Also, we aren't sure if massages (or what type of massages) really help relieve the pain.

---

## What is *Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness* (DOMS)?

Delayed onset muscle soreness (DOMS) is the sensation of muscular discomfort and pain during active contractions that occur 24–48 h after strenuous exercise. The initial symptoms are most evident at the muscle-tendon junction and thereafter spread throughout the entire muscle.[(ref)](http://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-3-642-28753-4_1018)

## Physiopathology of DOMS

The mechanism is not completely understood and several theories have been proposed, namely: [(ref)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/00007256-200333020-00005)

1. lactic acid
2. muscle spasm
3. connective tissue damage
4. muscle damage
5. inflammation
6. enzyme efflux

The underlying cause is probably a conjunction of 2 or more of these theories. However, ultimately, the underlying transversal cause is **muscle microtrauma**. There are a few interesting findings that support this:

- High-intensity eccentric contractions induce performance decrements and DOMS [(ref)](http://www.clinsciusa.org/cs/064/0055/0640055.pdf),[(ref)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02701367.1985.10605375?journalCode=urqe20#.VFwGhvmsVB0)
- Concentric exercises seems to cause no soreness [(ref)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00140137208924444#.VFwHrfmsVB0)
- Eccentric contractions are high force and are associated with muscle damage [(ref)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00635995)
- Creatinine, Potassium(K) (and sometimes Myoglobin) excretion (urine levels) and Creatine Kinase(CK), K and Neutrophil levels in blood are increased after intense exercise. This is also seen in [acute rhabdomyolysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhabdomyolysis), a condition in which damaged skeletal muscle tissue breaks down. (Ref: [Harrison's Principles of Internal Medicine, 17th Ed, Chapter 273: Acute Renal Failure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071466339))

---

## The effects of massage on DOMS

A massage MAY indeed reduce pain in DOMS [(ref)](http://bjsm.bmj.com/content/37/1/72.short), however, most studies' results are inconsistent and hindered by methodological flaws[(ref)](http://bjsm.bmj.com/content/32/3/212.short) such as lack of control of the [placebo effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo) or the subjectivity of pain.

A study by *Smith et al* suggests that sports massage will reduce DOMS when administered
2 hours after the termination of eccentric exercise. They also found lower CK levels, higher cortisol levels and a prolonged elevation of neutrophils in the blood of massaged groups [(ref)](http://www.jospt.org/doi/abs/10.2519/jospt.1994.19.2.93#.VFwMYfmsVB0). This might mean lower muscle trauma and inflammation due to a reduced migration of neutrophils (to the muscle) and higher levels of serum cortisol.

The increment in the blood flow to the muscles during a massage might also be implicated in the process, by restoring oxygen and nutrients required to muscle remodeling. However, there is no clinical evidence of this fact and a study strongly rebutes this [(ref)](https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/s-2007-973041)

Hyperstimulation of the nerve endings in the affected muscles might give a sense of pain relief, in a context of microtrauma. [(ref)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/00007256-200838060-00004)